# Why are the Leaflet/Mapbox zoom and layer controls missing markings?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

We're loading our own tiles using mapbox 1.5.2 with the following code:

```
var mapLayer = L.tileLayer('http://192.168.1.2/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                            {maxZoom: 18}
);
var satLayer = L.tileLayer('http://192.168.1.2/images/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                            {maxZoom: 18}
);
var hybridLayer = L.tileLayer('http://192.168.1.2/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                               {maxZoom: 18}
);
var satGroup = L.layerGroup([satLayer,hybridLayer]);
var baseLayers = {"OSM":mapLayer, "Sat":satGroup};
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

and get the following map:
[image]

What happened to the controls?  I should have a plus/minus in the zoom and the layers 'pancake stack' for the multiple layers.  FWIW, the controls work just fine.

Comment: Could you please provide your full code and any errors or warnings logged to your console? Here's how you can [access your console in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: Gerald, thanks for the Chrome console idea.  I've been using Firefox and it has all kinds of errors when loading - even the examples from the Mapbox website.

The Chrome console showed it had a problem loading the file 'icons-404040.png'.  Yikes!  As I noted in tmcw's answer, I am loading this onto a private network.  Do you know where I can get all the images I may need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When being used in an offline mode there are at least three files that are required, mapbox.css, mapbox.js and images/icons-404040.png.  I used the following url to get the png file (which will likely changes as versions change):
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.5.2/images/icons-404040.png

Create an images subdirectory at the level of your mapbox.css and place that file in it.  My app is working now.

Here is a pic of the file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've included the mapbox.js file, but not mapbox.css, or the wrong version of mapbox.css.

Comment: You are correct that it is a problem with the css file but I am unable to figure out why.  What I am doing is hosting the file locally because this is going on a closed network with no access to the Internet.  It has worked before using the local css file and I have recopied the file from the mapbox server with no success.  I will post the code as gerald requested but it is basically the simple map example on the mapbox developer's page.  Are there any other files that are required?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It turns out it is not a problem with the css.  It can't find local icon files.  I don't know why I thought it worked before.  Either it did (which seems unlikely) or I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the css file, you need to include a "map/images/" folder next to the css file containing :

- icons-4040.png
- icons-4040@2x.png

The second is used by mapbox for high resolution screen.

[image: icons-4040.png]

[image: icons-4040@2x.png]

You may also need to include other pictures if your mapbox theme is dark ( see [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/theme/)).

- icons-ffffff.png
- icons-ffffff@2x.png

Image are below but white background make them invisible.

[image: icons-ffffff.png]
[image: icons-ffffff@2x.png]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue affecting the '**Layer Control**' not being visible (even though they weren't exactly missing) and the **+**/**-** controls aligning slightly to the left

In my case I was using **MAPBOX.CSS** from CDN and it was due to a conflict with **LEAFLET.CSS**

Using either one or the other of the CSS files solved the issue. **MAPBOX.CSS** also seemed to affect my Marker Tooltip functionality so I personally went with **LEAFLET.CSS** and just retained MAPBOX.JS

The above issues contained the words '**Leaflet/Mapbox**' and '**controls missing**' which brought me here in the first place. Anyone else stumbling onto this post nowadays could very well share my particular issue and the **css conflict** between **Leaflet** and **Mapbox**.